# discriminant of subfield of $\mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For a field $K\subset \mathbb{Q}(\zeta_p)$    $~$($\zeta_p$ a primitive pth root of unity, p a prime), it seems to be the case that the discriminant of $K$ is $p^{[K:\mathbb{Q}]-1}$  (according to Sage).  How can I prove that/ is the proof implied by something written down somewhere?

I have a feeling this is somewhat deep so I ask it here; if it's insufficiently deep I'm happy to close it and ask elsewhere.

Comment: The Führerdiskriminantenproduktformel tells you that is it the product of conductors of characters, but all but the trivial character must have conductor p.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Führerdiskriminantenproduktformel tells you that is it the product of conductors of characters, but all but the trivial character must have conductor $p$.

Answer (score 11):

This would also work for non-abelian, and even non-Galois extensions: if $L/\mathbb{Q}$ is totally ramified and tamely ramified at $p$ and $K$ is an intermediate field, then $K$ is also totally tamely ramified at $p$, so the exponent of $p$ in the discriminant of $K$ is $[K:\mathbb{Q}]-1$ (Serre, Corps Locaux, Proposition 13).

Comment: This is (IMO) a better answer. First, the different (and discriminant) of a totally tamely ramified extension is certainly a simpler notion than understanding the conductor of an abelian extension. Second, it is more general. Of course, both answers are correct.

Comment: @ElectricPenguin  theres a very elementary definition of conductor in this special case: the smallest n s.t. $\chi$ factors through (Z/pZ)*-->(Z/nZ)*

Comment: @dessind'efantterrible To split hairs, I would say that this is a *computation* of the conductor in this case rather than a definition. The distinction is that this if you actually want to *prove* the Führerdiskriminantenproduktformel (in the abelian case) for a local extension $L/K$, you really need to grapple with $N_{L/K}(L^*)$ in some way (say via basic local class field theory), whereas one could compute (with a full proof) the different of a totally tamely ramified extension $L/K$ in a single MO comment.

Comment: @GHfromMO The extension $\mathbf{Q}_p(p^{1/e})$ with $e > 1$ prime to $p$ (for example) is certainly totally tamely ramified and is never generated by a root of unity. Perhaps you are thinking about the fact that an abelian extension of $\mathbf{Q}_p$ is cyclotomic (local Kronecker-Weber)?